# How to block Twitter / X login pop up on iPhone?

Tags: ios, safari, software-recommendation, google-chrome, safari-extensions

On windows there are browser plugins to block elements of a website in real time (right clicking on element for example.) What browser(s) or plugin(s) are available for iPhone to accomplish this task?

For example -- going to Twitter / X and it asks you to login, I can just select and block this element but I am unable to do it on mobile safari or any other browser I can think of for iOS.

Comment: You will need to create or find a browser extension to do this for you. Hopefully someone can name a specific one that it known to work. UserScripts might also work.

Comment: Something like 1Blockr on the phone will do the job.